# android spinner for list and "All" option

Tags: android, filter, android-listview, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have a android spinner that works like a filter for product listview. The spinner adapter has the list of Brand class objects. The listview then shows only the products with selected brand. Now I need to add to the top of the list another special option "All" that turns off the filter and shows all products.

I have implemented the adapter with creation of the fake Brand class instance so that I can add this to the Brand ArrayList used by the adapter but this is not ideal - all other objects are valid database objects so I would like to ask for better approach how to achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way which I am doing this in all my apps is equal. Add `All` item as first item to your spinner adapter and in your onItemClick you can do something like this :

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                    if(position == 0){
                          // show all products
                    } else {
                          // show the selected brand's products
                    }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }
    });
```

The best option which I had during my development is this one. I didn't saw any other way to achieve this.